# How to show Own Ad using AdMob in Android App

Tags: android, admob

I have my Android App. I want to show My Own advertise in App through AdMob.
Is It possible to show own ad in my app using Admob ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing are [AdMob Campaigns](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6162747). You can design your own ads to run in your apps, schedule them to run part of the time while regular AdMob ads are shown the rest of the time, and so on.

Comment: I believe you can just set the campaign to use 100% of your traffic, at which point there's none left for anything else.

Comment: @AkshayNandwana did you success did this?